Textview getting out of the parent layout in Android XML
Im having some issue with keeping the textview visible and in center of the parent layout
This is some what an expected output i want (this is a image an not a ui layout itself)

but as im not using this image, im trying replicate it with layouts and textview
but im not getting a expected output
this is what im actually getting

As you can see the dots/text is missing
Here is the code im using
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/appToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#e7e7e7"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/aboutPage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end|center"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="#fffdf6"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="15dp"
                    android:text="...."
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="#36332c"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


i know its mostly due to the margins I'm giving to the parent linear layout, but that is necessary

You can create simple custom view for this. I know you might think it's overcomplicated, but let me explain.
Problem
The main problems are margins and the textSize. Margins are clipping out the space and don't forget that dots belongs on the bottom of the line, so even with margins removed, you will have hard time centering the dots (textAlignment="center" and gravity="center" won't help).
Solution
Using custom view you can easily measure and calculate exact center position for dots based on view size and actual text size (which means only size of dots is measured).
class DotsTextView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attributeSet: AttributeSet? = null,
    style: Int = 0
) : View(
    context,
    attributeSet,
    style
) {

    private val text = "...."

    //Paint used for set text formatting (like color, size, ..)
    private val textPaint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG).apply {
        color = Color.parseColor("#36332c")
        textSize = TypedValue.applyDimension(
            TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,
            30f,
            context.resources.displayMetrics,
        )

        textAlign = Paint.Align.CENTER
    }

    //text bounds to store text measures
    private val textBounds: Rect = Rect()

    //Padding replacing the margin
    private val padding = TypedValue.applyDimension(
        TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
        15f,
        context.resources.displayMetrics,
    )


    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)

        //Draw the text in the centre of view,
        canvas.drawText(
            text,
            measuredWidth / 2f,
            measuredHeight / 2f + textBounds.height() / 2f
            textPaint
        )
    }

    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        //measure the text so we can properly set view size 
        //and get exact center for placing the text 
        textPaint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length, textBounds)
        //Set view size based on paddings and text size
        setMeasuredDimension(
            ((padding * 2) + textBounds.width()).toInt(),
            ((padding * 2) + textBounds.height()).toInt()
        )
    }
}

And use it in xml layout like this, don't forget to replace com.your.app with your actual package name.
<com.your.app.DotsTextView
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_gravity="center" />


Edited: You can adjust your layout like this by using the framelayout
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/appToolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#e7e7e7"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/aboutPage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/img_jordan">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"
                android:text="...."
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="#36332c"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

wrapping the linearLayout with a frame layout, you can maintain the outer border while ensuring that the text view is centered both horizontally and vertically within the parent layout.

thanks for the answer, but this is not working, and both the linear layouts are imprtant one is for border and one is for the background

Have updated the answer please look.

thanks for the code update, but its not working by just switching from linear to frame layout

Inside your AppBarLayout -> Toolbar -> below given layout
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/aboutPage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|center"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fffdf6"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="...."
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#36332c"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

Try this and you can change the margins as per your requirement.

Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately im not getting the text view showing, same output as added in the question, i tried to adjust the bottom margin by increasing and removing the above margin in the text view , but docent seems to work

is there any error or what issue are you facing? I'm not able to get it properly

No im not getting error , the issue im facing to show the dots/textview in the center of the linear layout, which ate currently totally missing

-- meanwhile maintaining the margins

But when I created this layout, then it is working properly in layout of XML. so are you using any other components as well? that might be causing issue here. and for your purpose you should be using the relative layout as you won't be able to achieve it using linear layout easily.

can you share the image if possible , as im using the same code but im not able to see the textview, please view the entire code here https://codeshare.io/KWjzqN
